# How can complements of open sets in the lower limit topology be closed?

Tags: general-topology

If we take a typical open set in the lower limit topology [a,b), how can its complement be closed when the definition of a closed set is one that contains all of its limit points. In this case the missing limit point is a.

Comment: You have a very nonstandard definition of a closed subset. They are typically defined as complements to open sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that given a topological space $X$, an $A \subseteq X$ and $x \in A$, we say that $x$ is a [*limit point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$ (in $X$) if every open neighbourhood of $x$ (in $X$) meets $A$.

As such, being a *limit point* of a set is wholly dependent on the underlying topology you are currently using/interested in.  While $a$ is a limit point of $A =( - \infty  , a ) \cup [ b , + \infty )$ in the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$, this need not be true when you use a different topology.  For instance, the set $[a,b)$ is an open neighbourhood of $a$ *in the lower limit topology* — it is an open set in *the lower limit topology* which contains $a$ — which is disjoint from $A$, and so $a$ cannot be a limit point of $A$ *in the lower limit topology*.